# In a loop, how do I get the text from an h3 element?

Tags: jquery

So I want to get the text on the h3 element, but I don't know how to get the text. I keep getting empty results. This was my last attempt:

```
    $('#budgetOverviewResult .budget-inner-table').each(function() {
        var insideText = $(this).children('h3:first').text();
        console.log(insideText);
    })
```

And here is the HTML

```
<td data-date="2014-09-01" class="budget-inner-table">
    <h3>supercalifragilisticexpialidocious</h3>
    ...some code
</td>
```

Comment: what is `row` ? Need some more code for context and html example

Comment: Please provide a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: It works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqmcuuuf/). Of course, with `onLoad` event and with `id="budgetOverviewResult"` on `<table>`.

Comment: @charlietfl I removed row. so you forget about it. In this case is not important.

Comment: code shown should work ( assuming table ID exists) so something else must be wrong. Create demo that replicates problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might help

```
$('.budget-inner-table').each(function() {
    var insideText = $(this).find('h3').eq(0).text();
    console.log(insideText);
    //rest of code
});
```

EDIT: Explained
OPs HTML code had no `id` tag which would cause problems because the JQuery selector wouldn't be able to find the element. Secondly, I've personally found using `.eq()` better than using a pseudo selector as `:first`.

Comment: Why would this work when the OP's code would not?  There's nothing wrong with this implementation, but I don't see how it solves some sort of problem that the OP's code had.  Just a different way of doing it.  Also good answers explain what they did and why.

Comment: different way to do exactly the same thing as OP code

Comment: I used to work at a place where I was dealing with 1000+ elements and using `.eq(x)` returned faster than `:first` but this is, like i said, a personal observation and preference.